# postgres server started to refuse connection

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

After ssh into the ubuntu 20.04 server running postgresql 14, the `sudo -u Postgres sql Postgres` command returns an error message:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

Here is the pg_hba.conf:

```
local   all             all                                     trust #<<==changed from peer to trust. but error is the same
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
#ssl
hostssl all             all             0.0.0.0/0               scram-sha-256 c>
```

Here is the nodejs connection string:

```
const Sql = require("sequelize");  //sequelize 6.x
db = new Sql('mydb', 'postgres', `${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}`, {
        host: 'localhost',
        dialect: 'postgres',
        port:5432,
        //operatorsAliases: false
    } );
```

The connection request initialized on the same server returns an error:

```
r]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
0|server  |     at Client._connectionCallback (/home/node-xyz/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:130:24)
0|server  |     at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/home/node-xyz/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:305:19)
0|server  |     at Client._handleErrorEvent (/home/node-xyz/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:315:19)
0|server  |     at Connection.emit (node:events:513:28)
0|server  |     at Socket.reportStreamError (/home/node-xyz/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:52:12)
0|server  |     at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
0|server  |     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
0|server  |     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
0|server  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
0|server  |   parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
0|server  |       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16) {
0|server  |     errno: -111,
0|server  |     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
0|server  |     syscall: 'connect',
0|server  |     address: '127.0.0.1',
0|server  |     port: 5432
0|server  |   },
0|server  |   original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
```

Comment: The error is "No such file or directory". So it could be a missing directory.

Comment: Hi @kometen, which file or directory can be missing here?

Comment: The folder /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 is missing. Maybe a reinstall of postgresql will help?

Comment: Look in the database servers log file.  Most locally, it is not running.

Comment: List to postgres clusters of the server (pg_lsclusters for ubuntu for example, the command depends on the OS of the server) and check if the status of the cluster you're trying to reach is online. If the cluster isn't online try turning it on and see if that yields an error message.

Comment: the  things puzzling is that there is no change on psql configuration. Is it file corruption related?

Comment: Here is the pg_clusters output:                       Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
14  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/14/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log
The server is down.

Comment: That would explain the psql error then. Can you try running pg_ctlcluster 14 main start? You might need to sudo to get sufficient privileges.